# How send answer in group poll?

Tags: telethon

How can I vote poll in a group? I need to select 1 of the options, but I have not found a function that is responsible for this

I can create poll, but not vote as client like [Lonami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759433/lonami) show in another question

```
await client.send_message('@username',file=types.InputMediaPoll(
    poll=types.Poll(
        id=..., # type: long (random id)
        question=..., # type: string (the question)
        answers=... # type: list of PollAnswer (up to 10 answers)
    )
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [message.click(index)](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.click) as stated in the docs.

```py
message = await client.get_messages(chat, ids=xx) 
# ^ get the message containing poll or from events
await message.click(0)  # index starts from 0 == first
```

For multiple choice polls, pass a list of indexes.